# What is the Windows 7 search syntax for exact PART of a filename?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I want to search for a file with the exact string "02-02-002" in it's filename, the actual filename is "02-02-002 rev-C.doc"

[This Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1162403/windows-search-for-exact-filename-and-extension-only) suggest that for Windows 10 the following should work:

```
name:02-02-002
```

However that returns many results that don't contain that name:
[image]

I tried the exact match syntax with a wildcard but that yielded no results:

```
name:=02-02-002*
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the string in quotes by itself?

Comment: Yes, have tried quoting it, doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to search for a file with the exact string "02-02-002" in it's filename

`02-02-002` works for me.

[image]

Comment: I just tried the same syntax as you and it still gives incorrect results: https://www.screencast.com/t/XPhxsWKEGJus I also checked to see if that string appears in the other files in the results and it isn't. It's a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

This would do it: **~="02-02-002"**

[Exact part match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUCo4.png)

Comment: I confirm that this is the correct answer, the quotes don't seem absolutely necessary though. Damn Microsoft for making it so hard to find how to do something so basic.