# Search for files by file name (not location)

Tags: windows-search

I am trying to find any files or folders that match some name. This and only this. The problem is that in my search results I am also getting any file or folder that has the search text **as part of its location**.

For example, when I search "Program Files" for "Temp", the result is thousands of thousands of files that have "Temp" as part of their location.

How do I do a search where the result is just the files and folders
**named** "Temp" (or, for example, "Template") themselves and not their
path or contents?

[image: screenshot showing search results for "Temp" (many files, not named "Temp")]

Comment: You have to specify to search in the file-name. Search for `name:temp`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Search for exact filename and extension only](https://superuser.com/questions/1162403/windows-search-for-exact-filename-and-extension-only)

Comment: Not really. His screenshot shows a solution but the questions are different. I am not necessarily looking for only files/folders named exactly "Temp". E.g. folders named "Template" should also show...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `name:temp` will find files called “temp” or “template”,
  but not “attempt”, “badtempered”, “contemplate” or “distemper”. 
  To get those, try `filename:*temp`. 
  It seems that `name` and `filename` sometimes get different results,
  at least on some versions of Windows.
- While searching with `name` or `filename` will not match files
  simply because they are ***in*** a folder whose name contains “temp”,
  it will still find those folders themselves. 
  To get just the files, use

  ```
  filename:*temp -type:folder
  ```

  where the `-` (minus sign, also known as hyphen)
  means “NOT” (i.e., subtract those results).
- Some people will tell you to use `kind:folder` instead of `type:folder`. 
  Warning: `type:folder` means actual folders,
  while `kind:folder` means actual folders and also files like `.zip` files. 
  If you have a file called “template.zip”, then
  `filename:*temp -type:folder` will find it, but
  `filename:*temp -kind:folder` will not.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from [a comment](https://superuser.com/q/1629891/150988#comment2489058_1629891) by [Robert](https://superuser.com/users/62676/robert).

Use `name:Temp` rather than just `Temp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for what you want just entering double quotes, for example (as you need):

```
"Temp"
```

Comment: Adding double quotes did not solve the issue. "Irrelevant" files/folders are still shown.

Comment: You can also add .extension to "remove" some files and also add * to search for a file that you don't know completely.